# Number of ways to generate a pair of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

For a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ and a matrix $M\in \mathbb{F}_p^{n\times \ell}$, let $\mathcal{C}$ be the collection of all matrices in $\mathbb{F}_p^{n\times \ell}$ that can be obtained by permutating the rows of $M$.

Assume $rank(M)=r$.

I am wondering is there a way to count the number of pairs $(M_1,M_2)\in\mathcal{C}^2$ when $rank(span(Col(M_1)\cup Col(M_2)))=2r-i$ for a given $0<i\le r$? (Say with respect to $p,r,i,\ell,n$?) Is this number $o(|\mathcal{C}|^2)$, assuming $\ell$ is fixed and $n\to \infty$?

Comment: It is $|C|$ times the number of $M_1\in C$ such that $$\operatorname{rank}(\operatorname{span}(Col(M_1)\cup Col(M))=2r-i.$$

Comment: It’s not clear what $n\to\infty$ means here. Is $M$ picked randomly? Randomly from matrices of rank $r?$

Comment: It only matters for the small o notation. Any way to compute the number of $M_1$, say with respect to $p,r,i,\ell,n$?

Comment: If $\ell=2$ and $M=(m_{ij})$ with $m_{i1}=1, m_{i2}=i.$ Then $\operatorname{rank}(M)=2$ and any $M_1,M_2\in C$ with $M_1\neq M_2$ has combined column rank $3.$ So when $i=1,$ you get the size of your set is $|C|^2-|C|\sim |C|^2.$ So $o(|C|^2)$ is not true in this case. I’d bet for any $\ell$ we can find a similar way to get a matrix of rank $\ell$ with  all but a few having combined rank $2\ell-1.$

Comment: For example, given $M_{ij}=j^i,$ with $n\geq \ell,$ then the rank is $\ell$ and I think most pairs $M_1,M_2$ will be in your set with $i=1.$ Your $o(|C|^2)$ conjecture might be true with $i>1?$